# What is better hashed or encrypted passwords?

Tags: php, security, hash, passwords

What is best for storing passwords? Should I be Encrypting or hashing password for you users table ?

What do you prefer,  and why? Could you please provide an example of secure password storage.

Comment: Please see http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/archives/000953.html

Comment: What speed? Are your running on a 486 chip or you have to hash 2.5 gazillion passes per sec? Dude, what the hack are you "optimizing" for?!

Comment: thanks rock! you saved me there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Considering passwords generally don't have to be checked / hashed / whatever that often *(they are when one is logging in, and registrering ; but that's pretty much it)*, speed is generaly not much of a concern : **what matters is security**.

What's generally done is :

- when a user registers, he types his (new) password)
- that password is [salted](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Salt_%28cryptography%29) + hashed, and the result is stored in database
- Then, when a user wants to log-in, he types his password
- What is typed is salted + hashed, and compared to the value stored in the database.

The *main* key is : never store the real password in the DB -- only a hash of it ; and salt it before hand, to avoid attacks by [rainbow-tables](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rainbow_tables).

And it seems this is already what you're doing -- so good point for you ;-)

Which hashing function should be used ? Well, sha1 is often considered as OK ; md5 is less OK now ; sha512 should be more than OK, I guess.

Comment: but isnt it overkill ? how about you , how do you just do it. ?

Comment: @Adam, considering security, there's no such thing as overkill ;-). Of course, it might be that your password hashing scheme is unbreakable and irrelevant because you may have a hardcoded admin account with "0000" as password. A system is only as secure as its *weakest* component and those are often hard to find. However, you can then be sure that it very likely *won't* be your password hashing what's the culprit and doing it wrongly or good usually takes the same amount of effort so I think it's a no-brainer.

Answer (score 1):

I'd do this usually:

```
<?php

function createHash($pwd, $salt = ''){
  $hash = '';
  if(!$salt){
    $salt = hash('sha256',mt_rand().time().$pwd.'2130A');
  }
  if($pwd[0] & 0){
    if($pwd[strlen($pwd)-1] & 1){
      $hash = hash('sha256', $pwd.$salt).$salt;
    }else{
      $hash = $salt.hash('sha256', $pwd.$salt);
    }
  }else{
    if($pwd[strlen($pwd)-1] & 1){
      $hash = $salt.hash('sha256',$salt.$pwd);
    }else{
      $hash = hash('sha256', $salt.$pwd).$salt;
    }
  }
  return $hash;
}

function getSalt($pwdHash){
  if($pwd[0] & 0){
    if($pwd[strlen($pwd)-1] & 1){
      $salt = substr($pwdHash,64);
    }else{
      $salt = substr($pwdHash,0,64);
    }
  }else{
    if($pwd[strlen($pwd)-1] & 1){
      $salt = substr($pwdHash,0,64);
    }else{
      $salt = substr($pwdHash,64);
    }
  }
  return $salt;
}

var_dump(createHash('testPassword',getSalt($pwdHashFromDb)) == $pwdHashFromDb); // true
```

- Salting provides higher security than a usual hash.
- The salt position depends on the entered password, and thus this makes the salt less vulnerable to be captured.
- Raw password is never known or stored
- balance between security and speed (for websites).

Comment: it's a static salt. something like a secret key.

Answer (score 0):

Hashing rather than encrypting passwords can help protect you against insider threats.  Since the hash is a one-way process, for the most part users' stored, hashed passwords should not be decipherable.  Rather, you can only run newly-inputted password attempts through the same has to see if the result is the same.

If you store encrypted passwords I would think that would imply that they could also be *decrypted*, which might be problematic if you have an untrustworthy insider.

This might be a good answer to the [interview question](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/NewInterviewQuestionsForSeniorSoftwareEngineers.aspx), "How can you stop your DBA from making off with a list of your users’ passwords?"

I have posted a question here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10308694/what-is-the-right-method-for-encoding-hashed-passwords-for-storage-in-ravendb with some sample code.  Though the question itself might prove to be boneheaded, perhaps the code sample can be useful to you, if the c# code is intelligible.